# Application of the mean value theorem $x\big(f(\tfrac{x}{n})-f(\tfrac{x-y}{n})\big)=O\Big(\vert y\vert f\big(\tfrac{x-y}{n}\big)\Big)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was reading a book and I've just found the following argument. Consider $n>1$ and a smooth one-dimensional function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\vert x\vert\gg \vert y \vert$. Then, applying the Mean-Value Theorem the following holds (according to the author): $$
x\big(f(\tfrac{x}{n})-f(\tfrac{x-y}{n})\big)=O\Big(\vert y\vert f\big(\tfrac{x-y}{n}\big)\Big).
$$
Now I am wondering how to prove this. What mostly surprise me is that there is no derivative in the right-hand side, and so I don't understand how is the author applying the MVT. Is this true or do I need some extra hypotheses? I have tried to prove it by directly using the MVT but I couldn't conclude, basically because I always obtained a derivative in the right-hand side, which I don't know how to handle.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems a little weird. Suppose $f(x)=e^x, y=1,n=2.$ The alleged inequality would be

$$x(e^{x/2} - e^{(x-1)/2}) = O(e^{(x-1)/2}),$$

which reduces to $xe^{x/2}(1-e^{-1/2})=O(e^{(x/2}).$ That clearly fails as $x\to \infty.$